# How to prevent an application from finding out what other processes are running?

Tags: windows

As the title says. More specifically, how do I prevent an application from using [code like this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682623(v=vs.85).aspx) from Microsoft”s site: [Enumerating All Processes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682623(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: why? This would be malware functionality and I doubt that this is allowed to discuss here.

Comment: @magicandre1981 The rule on malware/pirating/etc is basically, if it isn't explicitly said or the **only** possible solution this could be used for is something illegal, it's not against the rules. I could think of plenty of reasons to need to do this that aren't illegal, so it's not against the rules.

Comment: It might still be helpful to know why. I don't think this can be done without using some kind of tool.

Comment: The idea here is to stop software from reading information it honestly has no right to- for instance gathering information about what software I use in order to sell it to other parties. I should have the ability to choose what information is available to programs running on my computer.